# What type of space should be before 第?

Tags: typesetting

When writing the title of a book name together with the volume number, what type of space (if any) is usually used? (The context is the listing on a website.)

> `\u20`: `そらのおとしもの 第01巻`

or

> `\u3000`: `そらのおとしもの　第01巻`

Should there even be a space?

Comment: If you google 第01巻, everything that shows up on the first page has `\u20` rather than the fullwidth `\u3000`, showing that at least `\u20` is widely used in practice.